# when i run this script it tells IdentationError in the else line,why?

Tags: python

```
#Returns the sum of num1 and num2
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

#Returns the result of subtracting num1 - num2
def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

#Returns the result of multiplying num1 * num2
def mul(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

#Returns the result of dividing num1 / num2
def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2


def main():
    operation = input("What do you want to do(+,-,*,/): ")
    if(operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '*' and operation != '/' ):
       #invaid operation
       print("you must enter a valid operation")
    else:
        var1 = int(input("emter num1: "))
        var2 = int(input("Enter num2: "))
            if(operation == '*'):
             print(add(var1, var2))
             elif(operation == '/'):
                print(div(var1, var2))
            elif(operation == '-'):
                print(sub(var1, var2))
            elif:
                print(mul(var1, var2)) 


main()
```

Comment: You've got mixed tabs and spaces, to start, but that's only the first of your indentation problems. Stop using tabs. Configure your editor to insert spaces when you hit the tab key.

Comment: may you please be detailed, i am confuse.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole `if` and `elif` block is intended wrong. The correct intendation would look like this:

```
else:
    var1 = int(input("emter num1: "))
    var2 = int(input("Enter num2: "))
    if(operation == '*'):
        print(add(var1, var2))
    elif(operation == '/'):
        print(div(var1, var2))
```

and so on. You should concider [reading more about indentation in python](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) before continuing. It is not only required in Python, but also a best-practice in every language (as far as I'm aware) to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses whitespace to decide how code is grouped together.

This runs `bar` and `baz` is `foo` is true:

if foo:
      bar()
      baz()

This runs `bar` if `foo` is true, and always runs `baz`:

```
if foo:
  bar()
baz()
```

This doesn't work at all:

```
if foo:
  bar()
   baz()
```

If your indentation is inconsistent, Python will throw an error and give up.

In your case, you seem to have bad indentation here:

```
if(operation == '*'):
 print(add(var1, var2))
 elif(operation == '/'):
    print(div(var1, var2))
elif(operation == '-'):
    print(sub(var1, var2))
elif:
    print(mul(var1, var2))
```

You have `print` indented three spaces fewer than it should (it's part of the block for the `if` statement) and the following `elif` block is indented by one space more than it should (it should be at the same level as the `if` statement)

```
if(operation == '*'):
  print(add(var1, var2))
elif(operation == '/'):
  print(div(var1, var2))
elif(operation == '-'):
  print(sub(var1, var2))
elif:
  print(mul(var1, var2))
```

As an aside, you have multiplication and addition flipped!

Answer (score -1):

Your indentation was messed up. Try this:

```
#Returns the sum of num1 and num2#Returns 
def add(num1, num2):
return num1 + num2
#Returns the result of subtracting num1 - num2
def sub(num1, num2):
return num1 - num2
#Returns the result of multiplying num1 * num2
def mul(num1, num2):
return num1 * num2
#Returns the result of dividing num1 / num2
def div(num1, num2):
return num1 / num2


def main():
    operation = input("What do you want to do(+,-,*,/): ")
    if(operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '*' and operation != '/' ):
       #invaid operation
       print("you must enter a valid operation")
    else:
        var1 = int(input("Enter num1: "))
        var2 = int(input("Enter num2: "))
    if(operation == '*'):
        print(add(var1, var2))
    elif(operation == '/'):
        print(div(var1, var2))
    elif(operation == '-'):
        print(sub(var1, var2))
    else:
        print(mul(var1, var2)) 


main()
```